# can't download .apk file from server

Tags: linux

I have an apk file on my server (which is hosted on Hostinger) CentOS OS

now I want users to download that file from my server.

but when I point the url to the apk location it says 404 page not found while I know there are entire web sites dedicated to doing it.

I tried modifying htaccess file

```
AddType application/octet-stream .apk
```

then

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

then

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType application/octet-stream
</Files>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

even tried doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784154/4481968

PS. all other file formats get downloaded, even .APK file gets downloaded but not .apk (why is that?)

Comment: What's the name of the file? Under Linux, `example.APK` is something different then `example.apk`.

Comment: @Sven metal.apk, but I don't see how it's relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.apk files are blocked for security reasons by Hostinger, time to change my hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a media type problem, so fiddling with `AddType` and `ForceType` isn't going to get you anywhere.  A 404 error means, quite simply, that you don't have the file in the right place.  The webserver error log will tell you where Apache is looking, and it should be straightforward to work out what needs to change (the config or the file location) to get things working.

Comment: the file is in the right place as far as I know, as when I change the extension from .apk to .APK the file gets downloaded, and also tell me where and how can I get my hands on the webserver error log?

Comment: Ah, files are case sensitive in Linux; foo.apk isn't the same as foo.APK.  Where the server logs live depends on where it's configured to log to; look for `ErrorLog` in the config.

Comment: I tried searching for logs Hostinger says it doesn't provide detailed website logs for performance reasons. but I found some in .logs in ftp and they are the error messages. nothing related to this.

Comment: Wow, sounds like your hosting provider sucks pretty bad.

Comment: free hosting... :P but is there an workaround? I need to get those downloads working.

Comment: You get what you pay for.  There is no workaround, because there's no problem, you're just requesting the wrong filename.